# Vuex store strange behavior in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

The store data can be accessed in a component embeded in the HTML directly as:

```
 {{$store.state.notificationArea.cart.total;}}
```

This works fine, However, it doesn't work in the computed attribute of the same controller as:

```
computed: {
 total: function () {
     return this.$store.state.notificationArea.cart.total;
  }
}
```

Have been trying to resolve it for three days, please help.

Comment: you're making a typo in `conputed` it should be `computed`

Comment: please share your store code and check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed property is a function that returns a value it should be declared like `total:function(){}`, `total:()=>{}` or `total(){}` :

```
computed: {
 total:()=>{
     return  this.$store.state.notificationArea.cart.total;  
   }
}
```

And that property which you're referencing should be initialized like :

```
const state={
     notificationArea:{
                 cart:{
                    total:0,
                  }
            }
      }
....
```

[image: Edit Vuex Store]

Comment: did you fixed that typo?

Comment: Yes not working, there was typo here in StackOverflow only, I have edited my code.

Comment: you're welcome i added also an example in codesandbox